# mocha it.each does not work

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I tried to test url availability with mocha. To iterate over a list of links I used it-each. I require it as

```
require('it-each')();

describe('Async loop testing over link list', function () {
        this.timeout(15000);
        it.each(link_list, 'check link %s is available over https(auth)', ['val.title'], function (val, nextVal) {
            var arr = val.url.split(/^(http[s]*:)\/?\/?([^:\/\s]+)(.*)/);
            ///....
            checkPrivateLink("https:", host, path).then(function (res) {
                expect(res.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
                nextVal();
            }).done(null, nextVal);
        });
});
```

Now in theory this should work but it does not. It registers one test that is just called 'check link %s is available over https(auth)'. And finishes that test in 0-1 ms, which means it does not actually enter the test loop at all.

Any ideas how to get this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: it seems the it-each might work but it does not gete any data. link_list is always empty. however I put filling the list in a before(function(done){ ...}); Which for some reason does not finish its work before the it.each are started with empty data arrays.

Comment: Make sure that `link_list` is a JavaScript array (has a `length` field).

Answer (score 0):

My guesses:

- You want to use the [`testPerIteration`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/it-each#integration) option;
- `val.title` should be just `title`;